# Do i need a n extra wire to address this wiring issue?

Tags: wiring

Ok I pulled 1 cable which was- 14-2 gauge wire outside to a gazebo.    I want to hook up in order a switch(gfci)( All switches in this diagram will be gfci even if not needed).   A switch for a ceiling fan and light( no separation of light and fan needed here( will use pull chain or remote to switch,) then between the fan switch and fan I want to add a receptacle to add a small outdoor TV later.    None of this is energized as of now.  I wired all straight through and when I finished I realized that the recepticle is going to be controlled by the switch as well.  I want to make sure this is correct:::: So instead of removing the wire and installing a 14-3 may I buy a red travel wire or pull a black wire out of the existing wire I already have now and pull that straight from the hot on the light switch to the ceiling fan. ?   And use the black from the load(blanco)spot on switch and drop it off on the outlet and wire that normally(hot and neutral).  Will this work fine or is there an easier way to wire this?

Also, another question I have is that I know I didn't need to buy all gfci for the project but they were in my stick already and I will probably never use them for anything else.  They have been sitting in my basement for a few yrs.  So with all that in mind, if the gfci is wired first and the light switch is next does that have to come off the line side of the gfci? ( the taped off ones or can I wire straight through. 
     On another scenario I have 2 gfci next to each other, do I need to wire this off the line(factory taped off spots) or can I wire them straight through?
     Thx for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Reading thru you have lots of information you don't need, you are also greatly over complicating this. Do this connect a GFCI receptacle to the end of the 14/2 (line side terminals), then connect your switch and fan to the load side terminals of the GFCI.  Done.

Comment: I have an outlet between the switch and fan though.  I need another wire so that us what I have to do.

Comment: No, you need to change your order. Make the GFCI receptacle the first device, and then connect the switch and fan to that.

Comment: I have a gfci as my first device , then a fan switch then another outlet and then the fan.

Comment: @mikeh - get the message. Take out that outlet you put between the switch and outlet. Start with GFCI outlet first. Then the switch.

Comment: I got the message.  I am pulling a new cable from a hot source to the second gfci and pulling a single line from the switch to the FAn. Thx for your help

Comment: If you're doing it as described there, it should work.  The key is you needed another set of wires between switch and higher outlet.

Comment: Yes I was afraid that I couldn't get two cables through the PVC preinstalled in a leg of a gazebo  before building it fully.  I was able to get two 14-2 cables through so I should be fine. Now to terminate the UV cable.  What a pain in the arse.  Any advice ?

Comment: Ok. I have three wires in my box now where the switch is.   One from the below gfci which is where the hot comes in.    one that goes to the outlet and one to the fan.   All neutrals can be tied together if I'm not mistaken.  I have pig tails coming off the switch.  I'm unsure how to wire this part.  Can I just tie all the blacks together as well?

Answer (score 2):

You can't pull a single wire out of NM cable, because the single wire is not labeled for use individually, not even in conduit.  Single-strand THHN/THWN is labeled, but you can't just slapdash it next to the NM wire for several reasons, the first is it doesn't have a jacket like the NM. Also it is not routed together with the neutral so it will introduce eddy currents anywhere it is separated.

So you cannot just add a wire.  Your best bet is to pull 14-3 NM if that's what you want to do.  If you want to avoid this problem in the future, install EMT conduit and you can pull whatever.

If you want to power other things off a GFCI **outlet**, you carry hot+neutral+ground from the source to the GFCI outlet and attach to the `LINE` terminals.  Then you carry hot+neutral from the `LOAD` terminals to whatever other things you want to be protected by the GFCI.   It's as simple as that.

This may complicate your wiring plans, if you plan to feed the switch from the `LOAD` side of the outlet.

Comment: Ok i understand the single wire.  But the way I have tge gfci wired can be done right.   There won't be any issues?  So basically, for this wiring, gfci is powered directly from the circuit box, then it goes to a switch.  I don't want the switch controlling the outlet.  I need that always hot.  Do I still pull off the line to that switch?